# Install issue with phpChart Lite in Windows / xampp?

Tags: php, windows, xampp

I am having the same problem on the Windows-with-xampp side of the fence as Gerardo Tarragona is having on the Ubuntu-with-lampp side. Ref: [How to install phpChart lite library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030660/how-to-install-phpchart-lite-library)

I have tried a couple or few things and the roadblock I am hitting (see PHP error messages from browser below the code snippet) seems to be that the **conf.php** file is trying to **require_once('phpChart.php')** but I cannot find this file **phpChart.php** anywhere on disk. It does not seem to be with the phpChart_Lite extracted download. Can anybody shed light on this ?  What am I missing ?

Here is the conf.php file code:

```html
<?php
define('SCRIPTPATH','/phpChart_Lite/');
define('DEBUG', true);


/******** DO NOT MODIFY ***********/
require_once('phpChart.php');     
/**********************************/
?>
```

#### Warning: require_once(phpChart.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpChart_Lite\conf.php on line 10

#### Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'phpChart.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpChart_Lite\conf.php on line 10

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your system, change SCRIPTPATH to

```
define('SCRIPTPATH','/phpChart_Lite');
```

or

```
define('SCRIPTPATH','phpChart_Lite/');
```